# exporting to excel 2003 with one column with indian number format using NPOI

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using VS2008,ASP.net,C#.net,NPOI 1.2.3 dll.

I have a web applicaion which uses NPOI dll to export to excel 2003. How do I display a number with thousand separator in Indian style( 12, 12,34,567.89)in the exported excel sheet using program? The built in formula sum() should be applied on these exported cells with number format.

thanks in advance

the code is mentioned below.

protected void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the data to report on
            //var userAccounts = Membership.GetAllUsers();

```
        // Create a new workbook and a sheet named "User Accounts"
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("User Accounts");
        //var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("User Accounts");

        // Add header labels
        int rowIndex = 0;
        Row row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
        row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Username");
        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Email");
        row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Joined");
        row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Last Login");
        row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("Approved?");
        row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Qty");
        rowIndex++;



        //NUMBER FORMAT BEGIN
        CellStyle detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
        detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle.BorderTop = CellBorderType.THIN;
        detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle.BorderBottom = CellBorderType.THIN;
        Font detailCurrencySubtotalFont = workbook.CreateFont();
        detailCurrencySubtotalFont.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.BOLD;
        detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle.SetFont(detailCurrencySubtotalFont);
    detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("##,##,##,##0.00");

        //NUMBER FORMAT END

        row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
        row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("preejo");
        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("preejo@gmail.com");
        row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("01/Jan/2014");
        row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("27/Jan/2014");
        row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("true");
        //row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(((121234567.89).ToString("N", new CultureInfo("hi-IN"))));
        //row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(123456.78));
        row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(123456.78);
        //row.GetCell(5).CellStyle = cellStyle;
        row.GetCell(5).CellStyle = detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle;




        rowIndex++;
        row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
        row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("joby");
        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("joby@gmail.com");
        row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("01/Jan/2013");
        row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("27/Jan/2013");
        row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("false");
        row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(2323313.43));
        //row.GetCell(5).CellStyle = cellStyle;
        row.GetCell(5).CellStyle = detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle;

        //}



        // Auto-size each column
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.GetRow(0).LastCellNum; i++)
            sheet.AutoSizeColumn(i);


        // Add row indicating date/time report was generated...
        sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex + 1).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Report generated on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        //formula
        rowIndex++;
        row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
        Cell cell = row.CreateCell(5);

        cell.SetCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
        cell.CellFormula = string.Format("SUM(F{0}:F{1})", 2, 3);


        cell.CellStyle = detailCurrencySubtotalCellStyle;



        // Save the Excel spreadsheet to a MemoryStream and return it to the client
        using (MemoryStream exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Write(exportData);

            string saveAsFileName = string.Format("MembershipExport-{0:d}.xls", DateTime.Now).Replace("/", "-");

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", saveAsFileName));
            Response.Clear();
            Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
`String.Format("{0:#,##0}", yourNumber as Double);`

Comment: won't this insert the number as a string thus breaking some of Excels functionality after the doc is imported?